# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{5})$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

The question is :

> Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{5})$ are not isomorphic (I'm talking about ring isomorphism).

What I have done : suppose there is an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})\to \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5})$.

We have $f(1)=1$ and 
$$f(n+1)=f(n)+1, \qquad f(n-1)=f(n)-1.$$
Which leads to $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, but $f(\sqrt{5})^2 =f(5)=5.$ then $f(\sqrt{5}) \in \{\sqrt{5},-\sqrt{5}\}$, which is not possible since $\pm \sqrt{5} \notin \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5})$. Then, there is no such morphism $f$.

Am I right?

Comment: What kind of isomorphism/structures are you talking about? Vector Spaces or Field Extensions? It makes a big difference.

Comment: What is $x$ in "Which leads to $f(x)=x$,..."?

Comment: @Ed_4434 I'm talking about ring isomorphism.

Comment: @russoo $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, I corrected it.

Comment: In that case, note that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\Bbb{Q}[X]\(X^2 - 5)$ are the same thing.

Comment: let $\sigma$ being a ring morphism $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \to \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt {5})$ . define $\sigma(\sqrt{5}) = a$. since a morphism respects $\sigma(x^2) = \sigma(x)^2$ we get $\sigma(5) = a^2$. it is easy to see that $\sigma(p/q) = p/q$ for every rational $p/q$, since$ \sigma(1) = 1, \sigma(n) = \sigma(1)+\ldots+\sigma(1) = n$, $\sigma(1/n) = 1/n$. hence $a^2 = 5$ : problem.

Comment: Can you find an element $x$ in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt5]$ with $x^2=-5?$

Comment: @awllower : no I can't.

Comment: @Ed_4434 : and how do you show there is no ring morphism $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2-5) \to \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+5)$ ?

Comment: And this coincides with the answer by @JendrikStelzner. :D

Comment: @aziiri: I think your proof is essentially correct. Maybe you should just add a short remark which explains why $\pm\sqrt{5}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: @Ed_4434: it follows almost directly from the definition of a ring isomorphism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not isomorphic as fields: While $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{5})$ contains a square root of $-5$ (namely $i \sqrt{5}$), the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ does not (as it is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$).

They are however isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, as they are both two-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$ (because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ has $\{1, \sqrt{5}\}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis, and $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5})$ has $\{1, i\sqrt{5}\}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis).

Comment: Short, simple, accurate and elegant. +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider the fields $K = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $L = \Bbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5})$ and suppose that $\varphi$ is a field homomorphism.

If we look at $\varphi(\sqrt{5}^2)$ then we have

$$\varphi(\sqrt{5}^2) = \varphi(\sqrt{5})^2 = \varphi(5) = 5,$$

so for $\varphi$ to exist, there must exist an element $\varphi(\sqrt{5})$ in $L$ such that $\varphi(\sqrt{5})^2 - 5 = 0$, a contradiction. So $K$ and $L$ cannot be isomorphic.